# Can I solve this integral?

Tags: integration

Let $d,n~$  be positive integer.

$\int{y(1-y^d)^n}dy$

Is it possible to solve it? If you know the method, please teach me.

Comment: Perhaps a binomial integral is what you're looking for http://www.nabla.hr/CL-IndefIntegralB5.htm

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Expand the term $(1-y^d)^n$ using the binomial theorem, and multiply by $y$. Then you will simply have a polynomial, and polynomials are easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

As Eff answered, the binomial theorem seems to be the way to do it.

You will learn sooner or later that $$\int{y(1-y^d)^n}\,dy=\frac{1}{2} y^2 \,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{2}{d},-n;\frac{d+2}{d};y^d\right)$$ where appears the Gaussian or ordinary hypergeometric function (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)).